# How can I set default sorter and filters on antd table components?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using ant-design react components to make a dashboard and have used a [table component](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-head) where I can define how the filters and sorters once the data is populated.

[image: dashboard table page]

If have a requirement where I want to apply default sorting(descending) on `ID` column and in environment column I want `prod` to be selected by default(to show only prod alerts by default). Since I [can't ask usage question](http://new-issue.ant.design/) on ant-design website, I wanted to know if someone knows about it and can help me with this. I am open to a different approach if you can share.

```
function onChange(pagination, filters, sorter) {
    console.log('params', pagination, filters, sorter);

    let order_by = sorter.field;
    if (sorter.order == 'descend'){
        order_by = `-${order_by}`;
        console.log(order_by);
    }

    let offset = ((pagination.current - 1) * pagination.pageSize);
    let url = `${baseUrl}&offset=${offset}&ordering=${order_by}`;
    this.fetchResults(url);
}
```

output for console.log

```
>>> params Object { showQuickJumper: true, pageSize: 20, current: 1, total: 301 } Object { env: Array['prod'], incident_type: Array['loadChk'] } Object {  }
```

Comment: Set ` filteredValue` prop to desired value on the required column. Then when you are fetching the results, send this value along with the request and get filtered requests.

Comment: Above mentioned works fine for first call but I want these only for initial loading for the first time, after that user should be able to select or sort as per his requirement. I am looking into this but if you know you can point it out to me.

Comment: I'm facing this same issue. Did you find a workaround?

Answer (score 15):

Use **defaultSortOrder**  like `defaultSortOrder: 'descend'`

Answer (score 12):

You can pass a default the `sortOrder` value: This can be `ascend`, `descend` or `false`; that would allow you to set a default sort order.

https://ant.design/components/table/#Column

As far as the default filter goes, you need to set the `filteredValue` prop as @Panther has mentioned above.

Comment: When I used ` filteredValue` prop then I am not able to change the value. I have answered this question and given a solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `defaultFilteredValue` for setting a default filter value. Give the value you want to display as a string array.

Eg:

```
{
      title: 'STATUS',
      dataIndex: 'status',
      key: 'status',
      filters: createFilterArray(status),
      defaultFilteredValue : ['Open'], 
      onFilter: (value, filters) => filters.status.indexOf(value) === 0,
},
```

For default sort use `defaultSortOrder`. It can take `ascend` and `descend` as values.